# Pass an array of array as a parameter

Tags: arrays, delphi, delphi-xe4

I have such an array:

```
12 |  18  |  22   |   26   |   28  |  32   | 34  | 36   |  50 
16           23                       33           37
```

As you can see, it consists of two rows, but some have one element and some have two.

I'm trying to write a function that takes an array of arrays as a parameter.

I declared myself a type:

```pascal
type array_of_array_of_Byte = array of array of Byte;

function my_function(value_list: array_of_array_of_Byte)
```

And I call the function like this:

```pascal
my_function([[12,16], [18], [22,23], [26], [28], [32,33], [34], [36,37], [50]]);
```

But I get error:

> Ordinal type required

What am I doing wrong? I'm using Delphi XE4.

Comment: Please specify Delphi version and the exact source code. This works for me in Delphi 11.

Comment: The issue isn't really how to pass this as a parameter. The question is really how best to represent this data structure.

Comment: I use Delphi XE4

Comment: The ability to initialize a dynamic array from a constant array expression was added in XE7
How can I do it in XE4 version?

Comment: @Pele see the answer I just posted

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the ability to initialize a dynamic array from a constant array expression wasn't supported yet in XE4, it was added in XE7:

[Dynamic Arrays in Delphi XE7](https://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/2014_september_dynamic_arrays_delphixe7.html)

> There is a significant new feature in the Object Pascal language for XE7 and that is the improved support for initializing dynamic arrays and operating on them.
>
> ...
>
> So what's new in XE7? The Object Pascal language allows you to do a few new operations:
>
> - **Assign a constant array to a dynamic array**
> - Concatenate two constant arrays with the + symbol
> - Use the following RTL functions on any dynamic array (not just strings): Insert, Delete, and Concat

So, in your case, you have no choice but to simply build up your dynamic arrays manually the old fashioned way - using `SetLength()` and per-element assignments, eg:

```
type
  array_of_array_of_Byte = array of array of Byte;

procedure my_function(value_list: array_of_array_of_Byte);

... 

var
  arr: array_of_array_of_Byte;
begin
  SetLength(arr, 9);

  SetLength(arr[0], 2);
  arr[0][0] := 12;
  arr[0][1] := 16;

  SetLength(arr[1], 1);
  arr[1][0] := 18;

  // and so on ...

  my_function(arr);
end
```